# Saving model into Userdefaults crashes application swift

Tags: swift, codable, userdefaults

I am trying to save my model class in UserDefault but keep getting error of 
`-[__SwiftValue encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2825fc0a0'`

I am using codables and below is what my Model looks like

```
struct AuthModel: Codable {
    let token: String?
    let firstName: String?
    let lastName: String?
    let telephone: String?
    let userId: Int?
    let email: String?
    let isEmailConfirmed: Int?
    let isVerified: Int?

    enum AuthModelCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case token
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case telephone
        case userId = "user_id"
        case email
        case isEmailConfirmed = "is_email_confirmed"
        case isVerified = "is_verified"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AuthModelCodingKeys.self)
        token = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .token)
        firstName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        telephone = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .telephone)
        userId = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .userId)
        email = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email)
        isEmailConfirmed = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .isEmailConfirmed)
        isVerified = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .isVerified)
    }
}
```

The above model shows what I am trying to save in my UserDefault but I keep getting the crash when ever it tries to save this.

I use my user default as follows

```
public func saveCurrentUser(_ user: AuthModel) {
        put(user, forKey: userKey)
    }

    private func put(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        guard let value = value else {
            storage.removeObject(forKey: key)
            return
        }
        storage.setValue(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value), forKey: key)
    }
```

Comment: `Codable` and `NSCoding` are two completely unrelated, independent concepts.

Comment: I am using `Codable`

Comment: That's my point. `Coding` has nothing to do at all with the use of `NSKeyedArchiver`. You are trying to mix two unrelated serialization methods.

Comment: how do I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`JSONEncoder()`** to encode `user` to `data`. Then save this `data` to `UserDefaults` using the relevant `key`.

```
public func saveCurrentUser(_ user: AuthModel) {
    do {
        let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(user)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: userKey)
    } catch  {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also storing some string values

Comment: What string values are you talking about?

Comment: Do accept and upvote if the answer helped you. Happy Coding..

Comment: yes it did. Cheers @PGDev

Comment: I am trying to get the saved user and I got a nil returned any help please