# Deteting item in an array stored in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I am saving items in UserDefaults and it works fine. I simply append new elements to the array. now deleting the entire saved items is done but now I want to enable the user the ability to delete just one item instead of deleting the entire saved items.

below is how I delete all the entire array

```
public func deleteSavePropery() {
        delete(key: propertyKey)
    }
    private func delete(key: String) {
        storage.removeObject(forKey: key)
    }
```

NOTE, saveProperty is a Codable object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to retrieve the array if exists then delete the item finally save back

```
let storage = UserDefaults.standard

private func deleteItem(key: String,item:Item) {
    if let data =  storage.data(forKey: key) , var arr =  try? JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data) {
        arr.removeAll(where: { $0 == item})
        guard let res =  try? JSONEncoder().encode(arr) else { return }
        storage.set(res, forKey: key) 
    }
}
```

---

```
struct Item:Codable,Equatable { 
    let name:String 
}
```

Comment: I am saving a Codable object. do I have to decode it first or what?

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type '(_OptionalNilComparisonType) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'Bool'`

Comment: The initial error was `Extra argument 'where' in call` so I removed `where`  and was left with `{ $0 == item}`

Comment: above compiles with me , what current problem ?

Comment: do I have to do this to all the Objects I want to perfom this operation with? `class Item:Codable,Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    } 
    let name:String!
    // add init
}`

Answer (score 1):

You need to,

1. Fetch the `array` from `UserDefaults`.
2. Remove the `element` from the `array` based on your condition.
3. Save the `array` back to `UserDefaults`.

**Example-1:** removing the `element` from `array` based on the `index`.

```
func remove(at index: Int) {
    if let data = storage.data(forKey: "YOUR_KEY") {
        do {
            var arr = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
            arr.remove(at: index)
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(arr)
            storage.set(data, forKey: "YOUR_KEY")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

**Example-2:** removing a particular `element` from `array`.

```
func remove(element: Item) {
    if let data = storage.data(forKey: "YOUR_KEY") {
        do {
            var arr = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
            arr.removeAll { $0 === element }
            let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(arr)
            storage.set(data, forKey: "YOUR_KEY")
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am saving a Codable object. do I have to decode it first or what?

Comment: Yes. Like you did here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636494/saving-model-into-userdefaults-crashes-application-swift/56636630?noredirect=1#comment99863495_56636630

Comment: I dont get, do I need to decode before deleting of I encode before setting

Comment: Update the answer.

Comment: `Binary operator '===' cannot be applied to operands of type '_' and 'Item.Type'`

Comment: === or == depends on the type of the elements you're adding to the array. If it is a value type use == else use ===. For now replace it with ==.

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type '(Any.Type?) -> Bool' to expected argument type 'Bool'`

Comment: What type of elements are you adding in the array?

Comment: optional elements of an object

Answer (score 0):

`UserDefaults` doesn't provide any API to manage the contents of a particular key. In fact, it doesn't care what kind of content is saved there.

So, what you need to do is: extract the array from `UserDefaults`, edit it and then save an updated array to `UserDefaults`.